# how to use CCJumpTo in cocos2d-android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am new to cocos2d-android. I want to add CCJumpTo using touch event in my code. But I don't know how to fix it. plz help.

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: thanks but I need to use CCjumpTo in Cocos2d-android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override ccTouchesEnded in your CCLayer and create a point where you want the jump to go to
like this

```
    public boolean ccTouchesEnded(MotionEvent event) {

        CGPoint touch = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(
                CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY()));
        CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();


        aHero.runAction(CCJumpTo.action(2f, touch , 100, 1));

        return true;
    }
```

where aHero is the sprite you want to jump, it'll make the sprite jump [once] to the touched area and reach there in 2s with a jump height of 100

Comment: @ JiMMaR I am new to stackoverflow. so I am not sure what did u mean?